# How to create a zip file with the multiple files sharing the same names

Tags: perl, zip, 7zip

Can any one help me creating a zip file out of two files of the same name.this is for one of the testing purpose . if you have any zip file with the same files like a.txt and a.txt as contents please let me know. any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually very easy using [Archive::Zip](http://p3rl.org/Archive%3a%3aZip).

```
my $zip = Archive::Zip->new;
$zip->addString("test one", "a.txt");
$zip->addString("test two", "a.txt");
$zip->writeToFileNamed("test.zip");
```

Nothing very interesting happens when trying to extract it with the standard unzip tool:

```
$ unzip test.zip
Archive:  test.zip
 extracting: a.txt
replace a.txt? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: y
 extracting: a.txt
```

If you prefer slightly more interesting content you can, of course, use the `addFile` method instead of `addString`.